# What are the correct .cpu, .fpu Assembly entries for the Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-architecture, specifications, raspberry-pi4

I want to learn ARM Assembly for the Raspberry Pi, I found out that the following versions of the Raspberry Pi are using the listed cpu-fpu version, could anyone please tell me:

1. what the Raspberry Pi 4 is using as cpu-fpu (I guess cpu is cortex-a72)
2. where to find the exact cpu fpu specifications (I googled for the official ARM specifications but I could not find the fpu in the docs)?

Rasperry Pi:

- Zero
- 1A+
- 1B+

uses

- cpu: arm1176jzf-s
- fpu: vfp

the Raspberry Pi:

- 2B

uses

- cpu: cortex-a7
- fpu: neon-vfpv4

and the Raspberry Pi:

- 3B

uses

- cpu: cortex-a53
- fpu: neon-fp-armv8

[Introduction to Computer Organization: ARM Assembly Language Using the Raspberry Pi](http://bob.cs.sonoma.edu/IntroCompOrg-RPi/sec-progorg.html) see Table 9.1.4

Comment: Are you writing 32 bit or 64 bit code?  The RPi4 has an ARM Cortex A72 core.  So I guess `cortex-a72` and `neon-fp-armv8` should do the trick.

Comment: Yes I am 'writing' 32 bit code, at the moment I should possibly say 'I learn how to write 32 bit code'. Yes this is also my guess, but I am wondering where to find this information for the fpu?

Comment: It's a guess.  The RPi4 has the ARMv8-A instruction set (same as the RPi3), so `neon-fp-armv8` seems appropriate.  Note that you are unlikely to be able to notice the difference in available instructions as a beginner.

Comment: Thank you for comment, I just found this gist: https://gist.github.com/fm4dd/c663217935dc17f0fc73c9c81b0aa845 which says what you say.

Comment: Cool!  Copy the relevant table entries into an answer and post it to reap that sweet reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a more in depth search I found another source which answered my question.
I combined the relevant entries in the following table.

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
| Raspberry Pi        | .cpu             | .fpu             |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
| Zero                | arm1176jzf-s     | vfp              |
| 1 A+                |                  |                  |
| 1 B+                |                  |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
| 2 B                 | cortex-a7        | neon-vfpv4       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
| 3 B                 | cortex-a53       | neon-fp-armv8    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
| 4 B                 | cortex-a72       | neon-fp-armv8    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

[Introduction to Computer Organization: ARM Assembly Language Using the Raspberry Pi - Robert G. Plantz - Table 9.1.4.](http://bob.cs.sonoma.edu/IntroCompOrg-RPi/sec-progorg.html)

[fm4dd - GitHub Gists](https://gist.github.com/fm4dd/c663217935dc17f0fc73c9c81b0aa845)